# ASP.Net Ajax $find() Jquery Equivalent

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

Is there a JQuery equivalent of ASP.Net Ajax's $find() function?

```
$() != $find()
```

Answer (score 8):

There is not since `$find` returns the AJAX component related to the DIV element, and not the DOM element.  You could build your own plugin that shortcuts the find method.

Microsoft created `$find` as a way to link their ASP.NET AJAX components to the DOM.

Comment: Finally someone knows the true use of `$find()`

Answer (score 2):

There is not a 1to1 equivalent but what you want is $('selector')

Check out the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) on the different [selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

```
$find('MyComponent') would be $('#MyComponent')

$find('MyComponent',div) would be $(div).find('#MyComponent')
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just do the following, no muss, no fuss, straight to the point.

```
$('#' + <%=myControl.ClientID%>)
```

Comment: That assumes you're on the page that your rendered code is on, not in an external JavaScript file.

Comment: yup. i know that. actually i've been using $("input[name*=pnlSuccess]) to find the control. What I actually want is the object that $find() returns. it seems that the object that $find() return in ASP.Net Ajax differs from the object that $() in Jquery returns. I definitely noticed this when using Telerik Controls.

Comment: That's because $find() just returns a DOM Element, and $() returns a jQuery object wrapping an array of DOM Elements, nonetheless, $() is just as useful, probably more so.

Comment: actually, $find() doesn't return a DOM Element. its the $get() function that returns a DOM element...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find an element by its ASP.NET code ID rather than the generated ClientID (`ctl00_RealId`) then you can use this function. It just looks for elements that have an ID that ends with `_{the real ID here}`:

```
var $$ = function (id, context) {
    var $ = (jQuery) ? jQuery : return ;
    var el = $("#" + id, context);
      if (el.length < 1)
        el = $("[id$=_" + id + "]", context);
    return el;
}
```

For example, say your ID in your code is `pnlSuccess`, say a panel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSuccess" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

But in the rendered code it comes out as: `ctl00_content_ctl00_pnlSuccess`

calling `$$("pnlSuccess")` will find that rendered panel.

Comment: this could be very unreliable in UserControl situations where a lot of controls could end with the same ID but have a different prefix

Comment: In that case, using the `context` would make more sense.

Comment: yup. i know that. actually i've been using $("input[name*=pnlSuccess]) to find the control. What I actually want is the object that $find() returns. it seems that the object that $find() return in ASP.Net Ajax differs from the object that $() in Jquery returns. I definitely noticed this when using Telerik Controls.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a LOOOOOOOONG time overdue, but I think I have the kind of solution you're looking for. If I'm correct, you're looking for a `$find` jQuery substitute because you don't know the ID of the element (which `$find` doesn't have selectors as far as I know but jQuery is awesome with). I just ran into this issue using Telerik controls on a SharePoint page, so my object ID is some long crazy mess, and since Sharepoint 2010 is on .NET 3.5, I can't use a static ID.

The solution is simple, but it racked my brain for a while. `$find()` is searching by ID, which luckily we can return as a string through jQuery: `$("elem").attr("id")`. So basically what we do is use jQuery inside the `$find` function and it works. Here's a sample from my project:

```
var contextMenu = $find($("[id*=mnuContext]").attr("id"));
```

This worked for me, and is going to help me out a lot with the rest of my SharePoint solution.