# Difference between $find("id").focus() and $("#id").focus()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, focus, find

Sorry, but I am quite new to jQuery. I wondered, what is the difference between those two lines? I struggled quite a moment, because the solution with find did a postback of the page...

```
$find("<%=PopupInputPanelOkCancel1.FocusId%>").focus();
$("#<%=PopupInputPanelOkCancel1.FocusId%>").focus();
```

I guess that the $find returns a HTML object and the $ returns a jquery object or something like that, but I can't see why the first one does fire a postback...
Only the second version does really set the focus on the field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849266/asp-net-ajax-find-jquery-equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is *not* valid jQuery; the second one *is* valid jQuery.

Explanation:

A valid jQuery object is formed by wrapping `$()` around a selector. `.focus()` is a method of the jQuery object. Thus, the second statement is valid jQuery.

`.find()` is also a method of the jQuery object, so something like `$('#id').find('.class').focus()` is valid jQuery, but your first statement is meaningless in jQuery.

Comment: I don't agree 100% with you about the first statement being meaningless. I used the following code to show an AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender like this.
`var modal = $find(modalBehaviorId);
if (modal != null) {
 modal.show();
}`
Like @Brian Mains says in the referenced post ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849266/asp-net-ajax-find-jquery-equivalent)) : "Microsoft created $find as a way to link their ASP.NET AJAX components to the DOM."
So it is not valid jQuery, but it is still valid code, if you use ASP.NET.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I was not aware of that, as I've never used ASP.NET. I've edited my question to reflect that the statement is meaningless in a jQuery context.