# $find doesn't work in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file, find

I have a jQuery code that when click on a button in page, show some information (from database) in a asp:RadEditor.

My code work properly when it's inserted internally in page inside tag , but not working in .js file!

```
function setShowRow(btn, url) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",

                    url: "../" + url + "/EditMessage_JQ",

                    data: "{ 'key':" + "'" + btn + "' }",

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (Data) {
                        if (Data.d[0] != null) {
                            $("#MainContent_TextBoxMain").val(Data.d[0]);
                        }
                        if (Data.d[1] != null) {
                            $find("#MainContent_TextRadEditorAbst").set_html(Data.d[1]);
                        }
                        if (Data.d[2] != null) {
                            $find("#MainContent_RadEditorText").set_html(Data.d[2]);
                        }
                        $("#insert").css("display", "none");
                        $("#DiveditBtn").css("display", "block");
                        $("#DivcancelBtn").css("display", "block");
                    }

                });
            }
```

Comment: Are you simply missing the "`.`" character: "`$.find`"  I don't know the jQuery function particularly, but I'm pretty sure everything there is namespaced off `jquery` or its alias, `$`.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is an object, so you have to use the dot-notation: `$.find(...)`

Comment: no, "$" is not an object in this example, since $find returns the AJAX component related to the DIV element, and not the DOM element. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849266/asp-net-ajax-find-jquery-equivalent