# Differences between jQuery selector, find and get

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to know what is the real differences between all these ways to get an object in jQuery.

1. `$('[id*="partofthename"]')`
2. `$('#name')`
3. `$find('id_of_control')`
4. `$get('id_of_control')`

I did some research and I found that:

1. It's the right way to find a control by its ID, but it's the same as 2 and 4. Am I right?
2. The second one is a shorcut for number 4. `$get`. Isn't it?
3. `$find` is getting the object with properties and methods
4. `$get` is the same as `document.getElementById()`

Now for number 3. and 4. Big deal.
With `$find` and `$get` both give me objects. `$find` is for .NETs `findComponent()` function

`$get` & `$find` are shortcut functions Microsoft has built into their Ajax JavaScript Library.

But when we talk to DOM element and javascript object.

Comment: I've removed your part about recommending a JavaScript book. Recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think you'll have to clarify this a bit, there is no `$find` or `$get` in jQuery, there's `.find()` and `.get()`, and they don't do even remotely the same thing? You seem to be comparing apples and oranges, some jQuery stuff, some Microsoft stuff, and then som .NET functions?

Comment: @adeneo, thanks for your reply. That's why I'm asking because I'm really new  in this. If you can clarify that would be awesome.

Comment: @Matt, why I can't ask for a good book to read and learn? Someone with a great experience can suggest me one!

Comment: @MaximusDecimus: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/how-to-request-book-recommendations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 . `$('[id*="partofthename"]')` selects zero/single/multiple elements `id` contains `partofthename`

From [`Attribute Contains Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) Docs:

```
Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a 
given substring.
```

2 . `$('#name')` selects single element with `id` = `name`

From [`ID Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) Docs:

```
Selects a single element with the given id attribute.
```

3 . `$.find('id_of_control')` selects all descendants of element using filter `id_of_control`

From [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) Docs:

```
Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, 
filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.
```

4 . `$.get('id_of_control')` selects one of the matched elements matched by jQuery object ie., `id_of_control`

From [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) docs:

```
Retrieve one of the elements matched by the jQuery object.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. This is the `[{attribute_name}{compare}{value}]` selector, it select any element that has  an attribute `{attribute_name}` (`id`) which value `{compare}` (`*=` means **contains**) as of the text `value` (`partofthename`) http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/
2. The id selector. http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/
3. [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849266/asp-net-ajax-find-jquery-equivalent) and [this one](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/364074/get-and-find-Asp-Net-ajax-functions/)
4. same

Answer (score 0):

1. is a slow way to spell 2., and definitely not the right way to get an element by id
2. is the jQuery way to get an element by id
3. and 4. are MS-specific APIs in ASP.Net applications, 4. should be roughtly equivalent to 2. (except you don't get a jQuery object, you get a MSAL DomElement object)